# PHP-FPM: Operation not permitted

Tags: nginx, centos, php

When I try to open index.php in browser I see the error:

```
No input file specified.
```

In error.log:

2013/11/04 22:40:07 [error] 3435#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/index.php (Operation not permitted)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"

Configuration of the server:

- CentOS 6.4
- PHP 5.4.17 (installed from sources)
- Nginx 1.0.15

PHP-FPM works from user nginx.

```
$ ps aux | grep fpm
root      3460  0.0  0.7  29524  3428 ?        Ss   22:48   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx     3462  0.0  0.5  29524  2732 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www            
nginx     3463  0.0  0.5  29524  2732 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www            
nginx     3464  0.0  0.7  29524  3592 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www            
nginx     3465  0.0  0.5  29524  2732 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www            
nginx     3466  0.0  0.5  29524  2732 ?        S    22:48   0:00 php-fpm: pool www            
vagrant   3468  0.0  0.1   5532   720 pts/0    D+   22:48   0:00 grep fpm

$ ls -la /var/www
drwxr-xr-x   2 nginx nginx 4096 Ноя  4 22:34 .
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root  root  4096 Ноя  4 22:31 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 nginx nginx   17 Ноя  4 22:34 index.php
```

Switch on catch_workers_output doesn't help

Comment: You have no 'x' privilege for index.php, 'x' means execute. It should be 'rwxr-xr-x'

Comment: I never added 'x' privilege for php-files, that work via web-server, and there was no problems. But I tried to add 'x' privilege for index.php now - that didn't help for me

Comment: Ok, 'Operation not permitted' is absolutely an authority problem. In product environment, it should be better using an custom work account to deploy both nginx and php.  Here I notice you using 'root' to start php-fpm and the worker process actually working with 'nginx' account. And '/var' can not be accessed by 'nginx' account.

Comment: $ ls -al / | grep var

drwxr-xr-x. 18 root    root     4096 Ноя  4 23:16 var

/var has rights 'read' for all

Comment: ok, i created directory /www, change owner to nginx:nginx for directory /www and file /www/index.php, but it's still getting the error: FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /www/index.php (Operation not permitted)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"

Comment: Even if i run php-cgi  from console with command sudo php-cgi -b 127.0.0.1:9000 (i.e. from user root), i get the same error

Comment: See your php-fpm.conf? Try changing 'user' and 'group' to specific account? Also check your nginx account.

Comment: I changed user and group to another user. Command 'id nginx' return 'uid=497(nginx) gid=497(nginx) группы=497(nginx),501(vagrant)'. /usr/etc/php-fpm.conf content: http://pastebin.com/D7kUq64B /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf content: http://pastebin.com/DiEue6rQ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Problem was in non-existent path of setting session.save_path and not in list of setting open_basedir in php.ini

Comment: Most likely, the issue with `session.save_path` was incidental, and the sole problem was with the `open_basedir` value. Whenever this error appears in the nginx log, simply check the PHP log, and the exact cause of the error (most often lack of permission due to `open_basedir` restrictions) will be apparent.